# Proof of Generalized Pigeonhole Principle used in MIT OCW course 6.042 in Lecture 16.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle

The Generalized Pigeonhole principle states that :

If |X| >= K|Y|, then for all f:X -> Y, there exists **K+1** different elements of X that are mapped to the same element in Y.

Prove this.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @Aryadeva I was having trouble with this statement itself. I mean, there need not be necessarily only k+1 diff. elements, there can be more too. But this was the exact statement that was given.

Comment: @SoumyanilDas "there exists $K+1$ elements" is equivalent to "at least $K+1$ elements", it does not mean "exactly $K+1$ elements"

Comment: @angryavian I see. I did not know this. Thanks a lot. Now no worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposition is false.  For example,
let Y be a singleton and |X| = k.

If |X| > k|Y| and f:X -> Y, then
exists y with k > |f$^{-1}$(x)|.

Otherwise, for all y, |f$^{-1}$(y)| <= k;
X = $\cup${ f$^{-1}$(y) : y in Y };
|X| <= k|Y|, a contradiction.

Comment: The proposition is true for finite non-empty $Y$ if you replace $|X|\ge K|Y$| with $|X|>K|Y|$.

Comment: Wake up @DanielWainfleet, that's exactly what I proved.